# initialize value to a public variable of type list of a class using the object initializer

Tags: c#, generics, object-initializers

I have a generic class which contain only one data member of type list. Now I want to add value to that list using the object initializer of that generic class from my main method.

Here is my Generic Class

```
class GenericStore<T>
{
    public List<T> allData = new List<T>();
}
```

Here is My entry Point

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        GenericStore<Student> studentData = new GenericStore<Student>()
        {
           // I Have Write This Which Gives me Error

            /*allData =  new Student(new Guid(), "Subhashis Pal"),
            allData =  new Student(new Guid(), "x"),
            allData =  new Student(new Guid(), "Y"),
            allData = new Student(new Guid(), "Z")*/
        };

    }
}
```

This is My Student Class

```
class Student
{
    private Guid id;
    private string name;
    public Student(Guid id, string name)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you add a constructor to your store that takes a parameter of type T and pass a student to it?

Comment: Which error? Please mention it as well.

Comment: you really should edit your post and add the error message. Actually it is quite informative: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'Student' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Student>'`. This means that you have a type mismatch. If you would start researching the [compiler error code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0029) you could have figured this out on your own. :)

Comment: actually researching the entire title of your question gave me [this as the first result](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#collection-initializers). The posted answers are there. The only difference is that they are using cats ;) instead of students

Comment: Actually I get Confused about as the allData is the member of a class and i'm using object initializer. i understand the Cat example but i should figured out. Thank You. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It gives you an error because `allData` field is of type `List<Student>` in case of `GenericStore<Student>`, so in order to seed that field in object initializer you need to instantiate `List<Student>` collection and use its object initializer to add `Student` objects

```
GenericStore<Student> store = new GenericStore<Student>
    {
        allData = new List<Student> 
        {
            new Student(new Guid(), "Subhashis Pal"),
            new Student(new Guid(), "x"),
            new Student(new Guid(), "Y"),
            new Student(new Guid(), "Z")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ok Thanks A Lot. :)

Answer (score 1):

`allData` is a `List<T>`, and you were trying assign single object `Student` to it every time.

Fill `allData` using *object intializer* like following:

```
GenericStore<Student> studentData = new GenericStore<Student>
{
    allData = new List<Student>
    {
        new Student(new Guid(), "Subhashis Pal"),
        new Student(new Guid(), "x"),
        new Student(new Guid(), "Y"),
        new Student(new Guid(), "Z"),
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you confused how object initialisers work. This:

```
GenericStore<Student> studentData = new GenericStore<Student>()
{
    allData =  new Student(new Guid(), "Subhashis Pal"),
    allData =  new Student(new Guid(), "x"),
    allData =  new Student(new Guid(), "Y"),
    allData = new Student(new Guid(), "Z")
};
```

is incorrect because a field cannot be assigned multiple times, and `Student` is not compatible with `List<Student>`. The correct way to do this is

```
GenericStore<Student> studentData = new GenericStore<Student>()
{
    allData = new List<Student>() 
    {
        // and you create your student objects *here*
    }
};
```

You need to properly assign a `List<Student>` to `allData`. And then, you can use a *list* initializer to initialise the list with the student objects.